# Create coffeescript class

Tags: coffeescript

I have simple class in coffeescript (this class is located in file.js.coffee):

```
class ExampleClass
  constructor: (arguments) ->   

  makeSTH: (page) -> 

  makeSTHElse: (data) =>
```

I have another coffee file. I included above file and I tried to create instance of ExampleClass this way:

```
/#= require file.js.coffee

class ExampleClass2
  constructor: (arguments) -> 
    @ex = new ExampleClass(sth)
```

But I got something like this:

```
ReferenceError: ExampleClass is not defined
```

I don't know how to correctly reference to ExampleClass. Thanks for all answers and sorry for my English.

Comment: `/#=` is not a directive have you tried `//= file.js.coffee`

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript will compile each of the source file as a separated compilation unit. Each of the compilation unit will be wrapped inside a block, so that the global namespace won't be polluted by mistake. So, `ExampleClass` actually get compiled to something like:

```
(function () {
  var ExampleClass;
  ExampleClass = function (args) {}
  ...
}).call(this);
```

You can see that `ExampleClass` can only be accessed from the same source. In order to access it from other source file, you need to bind it to `window`.

```
class window.ExampleClass
  constructor: (args) ->
  ...
```

PS. you're not allowed to use `arguments` as formal parameter name in CoffeeScript, as it has special meaning in JavaScript.

And `/#= require file.js.coffee` is not valid in CoffeeScript, you need to remove the leading `/`. I think that's just a typo.

Comment: Yup. You can also do `class @ExampleClass` as well, which will bind it to `window` as well. It results in `this.ExampleClass = function (args) {}...`, where `this` is the `window` context.